# Focussing on new subgoals in Eisbach

Tags: isabelle

In Eisbach I can use `;` to apply a method to all new subgoals created by a method.
However, I often know how many subgoals are created and would like to apply different methods to the new subgoals.
Is there a way to say something like "apply method X to the first new subgoal and method Y to the second new subgoal"?

Here is a simple use case:

I want to develop a method that works on 2 conjunctions of arbitrary length but with the same structure. 
The method should be usable to show that conjunction 1 implies conjunction 2 by showing that the implication holds for each component.
It should be usable like this:

```
lemma example:
  assumes c: "a 0 ∧ a 1 ∧ a 2  ∧ a 3"
    and imp: "⋀i. a i ⟹ a' i"
  shows "a' 0 ∧ a' 1 ∧ a' 2 ∧ a' 3"
proof (conj_one_by_one pre: c)
  show "a 0 ⟹ a' 0" by (rule imp)
  show "a 1 ⟹ a' 1" by (rule imp)
  show "a 2 ⟹ a' 2" by (rule imp)
  show "a 3 ⟹ a' 3" by (rule imp)
qed
```

When implementing this method in Eisbach, I have a problem after using `rule conjI`. 
I get two subgoals that I want to recursively work on, but I want to use different facts for the two cases.

I came up with the following workaround, which uses artificial markers for the two subgoals and is kind of ugly:

```
definition "marker_L x ≡ x"
definition "marker_R x ≡ x"

lemma conjI_marked: 
  assumes "marker_L P" and "marker_R Q"
  shows "P ∧ Q"
  using assms unfolding marker_L_def marker_R_def by simp


method conj_one_by_one uses pre = (
    match pre in 
      p: "?P ∧ ?Q" ⇒ ‹
        (unfold marker_L_def marker_R_def)?, 
        rule conjI_marked;( 
            (match conclusion in "marker_L _" ⇒ ‹(conj_one_by_one pre: p[THEN conjunct1])?›)
          | (match conclusion in "marker_R _" ⇒ ‹(conj_one_by_one pre: p[THEN conjunct2])?›))›)
    | ((unfold marker_L_def marker_R_def)?, insert pre)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but you might be able to derive some useful information from what is stated here.

> In Eisbach I can use ; to apply a method to all new subgoals created
>   by a method. However, I often know how many subgoals are created and
>   would like to apply different methods to the new subgoals. Is there a
>   way to say something like "apply method X to the first new subgoal and
>   method Y to the second new subgoal"?

You can use the standard tactical `RANGE` to define your own tactic that you can apply to consecutive subgoals. I provide a very specialized and significantly simplified use case below:

```
ML‹

fun mytac ctxt thms = thms
  |> map (fn thm => resolve_tac ctxt (single thm))
  |> RANGE

›

lemma 
  assumes A: A and B: B and C: C
  shows "A ∧ B ∧ C"
  apply(intro conjI)
  apply(tactic‹mytac @{context} [@{thm A}, @{thm B}, @{thm C}] 1›)
  done
```

Hopefully, it should be reasonably easy to extend it to more complicated use cases (while being more careful than I am about subgoal indexing: you might also need `SELECT_GOAL` to ensure that the implementation is safe). While in the example above `mytac` accepts a list of theorems, it should be easy to see how these theorems can be replaced by tactics and with some further work, the tactic can be wrapped as a higher-order method.

---

> I want to develop a method that works on 2 conjunctions of arbitrary
>   length but with the same structure. The method should be usable to
>   show that conjunction 1 implies conjunction 2 by showing that the
>   implication holds for each component. It should be usable like this:

**UPDATE**

Having had another look at the problem, it seems that there exists a substantially more natural solution. The solution follows the outline from the original answer, but the meta implication is replaced with the HOL's object logic implication (the 'to and fro' conversion can be achieved using `atomize (full)` and `intro impI`):

```
lemma arg_imp2: "(a ⟶ b) ⟹ (c ⟶ d) ⟹ ((a ∧ c) ⟶ (b ∧ d))" by auto

lemma example:
  assumes "a 0 ∧ a 1 ∧ a 2 ∧ a 3" 
    and imp: "⋀i. a i ⟹ a' i"
  shows "a' 0 ∧ a' 1 ∧ a' 2 ∧ a' 3"
  apply(insert assms(1), atomize (full))
  apply(intro arg_imp2; intro impI; intro imp; assumption)
  done
```

---

LEGACY (this was part of the original answer, but is almost irrelevant due to the UPDATE suggested above)

If this is the only application that you have in mind, perhaps, there is a reasonably natural solution based on the following iterative procedure:

```
lemma arg_imp2: "(a ⟹ b) ⟹ (c ⟹ d) ⟹ ((a ∧ c) ⟹ (b ∧ d))" by auto

lemma example:
  assumes c: "a 0 ∧ a 1 ∧ a 2 ∧ a 3"
    and imp: "⋀i. a i ⟹ a' i"
  shows "a' 0 ∧ a' 1 ∧ a' 2 ∧ a' 3"
  using c
  apply(intro arg_imp2[of ‹a 0› ‹a' 0› ‹a 1 ∧ a 2 ∧ a 3› ‹a' 1 ∧ a' 2 ∧ a' 3›])
  apply(rule imp)
  apply(assumption)
  apply(intro arg_imp2[of ‹a 1› ‹a' 1› ‹a 2 ∧ a 3› ‹a' 2 ∧ a' 3›])
  apply(rule imp)
  apply(assumption)
  apply(intro arg_imp2[of ‹a 2› ‹a' 2› ‹a 3› ‹a' 3›])
  apply(rule imp)
  apply(assumption)
  apply(rule imp)
  apply(assumption+)
  done
```

I am not certain how easy it would be to express this in Eisbach, but it should be reasonably easy to express this in `Isabelle/ML`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use `RANGE` to do what I wanted, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pointers from user9716869, I was able to write a method that does what I want:

```
ML‹

fun split_with_tac (tac1:  int -> tactic) (ts: (int -> tactic) list) (i: int) (st: thm): thm Seq.seq =
    let 
      val st's = tac1 i st
      fun next st' = 
        let 
          val new_subgoals_count = 1 + Thm.nprems_of st' - Thm.nprems_of st 
        in
          if new_subgoals_count <> length ts then Seq.empty
          else
            RANGE ts i st'
        end
    in
      st's |> Seq.maps next
    end


fun tok_to_method_text ctxt tok =
    case Token.get_value tok of
      SOME (Token.Source src) => Method.read ctxt src
    | _ =>
        let
          val (text, src) = Method.read_closure_input ctxt (Token.input_of tok);
          val _ = Token.assign (SOME (Token.Source src)) tok;
        in text end 

val readText: Token.T Token.context_parser = Scan.lift (Parse.token Parse.text)

val text_and_texts_closure: (Method.text * Method.text list) Token.context_parser =
  (Args.context -- readText -- (Scan.lift \<^keyword>‹and› |-- Scan.repeat readText)) >> (fn ((ctxt, tok), t) =>
    (tok_to_method_text ctxt tok, map (tok_to_method_text ctxt) t));

›

method_setup split_with = 
‹text_and_texts_closure >> (fn (m, ms) => fn ctxt => fn facts =>
   let
     fun tac m st' =
       method_evaluate m ctxt facts
     fun tac' m i st' =
       Goal.restrict i 1 st'
       |> method_evaluate m ctxt facts
       |> Seq.map (Goal.unrestrict i)
      handle THM _ => Seq.empty
     val initialT: int -> tactic = tac' m
     val nextTs: (int -> tactic) list = map tac' ms
   in SIMPLE_METHOD (HEADGOAL (split_with_tac initialT nextTs)) facts end)
›



lemma 
  assumes r: "P ⟹ Q ⟹ R"
    and p: "P" 
    and q: "Q"
  shows "R"
  by (split_with ‹rule r› and ‹rule p›  ‹rule q›)

method conj_one_by_one uses pre = (
    match pre in 
      p: "?P ∧ ?Q" ⇒ ‹split_with ‹rule conjI› and 
                            ‹conj_one_by_one pre: p[THEN conjunct1]›
                            ‹conj_one_by_one pre: p[THEN conjunct2]››
      | insert pre)

lemma example:
  assumes c: "a 0 ∧ a 1 ∧ a 2  ∧ a 3"
    and imp: "⋀i. a i ⟹ a' i"
  shows "a' 0 ∧ a' 1 ∧ a' 2 ∧ a' 3"
proof (conj_one_by_one pre: c)
  show "a 0 ⟹ a' 0" by (rule imp)
  show "a 1 ⟹ a' 1" by (rule imp)
  show "a 2 ⟹ a' 2" by (rule imp)
  show "a 3 ⟹ a' 3" by (rule imp)
qed
```

Comment: It seems that there exists an even more natural solution based on the iterative procedure from my answer: see the update.